# How to have onclick() event as well as HTML5 form validation together?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, onclick

I have created a form using html5 form validation for my website. However, validation part works only if I dont add onclick=somefunction() in submit button. If I add onclick event, it skips the validation part and directly executes the onclick() event. Here is the code for submit button..How to ensure both validation part, as well as onclick event, executes?

```
<button type="submit" class="signupbtn" onclick="clickAlert()">Request for 
Registration</button>
function clickAlert() {
alert("You will get a call to verify your Registration soon!");
 }
```

Comment: please share the form markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the onclick event. It is caused by the `alert`.

You are pulling the focus away from the form which causes the browser generated error message to be removed at the instant it would normally be displayed.

Don't use `alert()`. Instead, modify the DOM of the page to display the message there.

Comment: how to do that? sorry but i am a begginer